# How to add input validations in angular 2 primeng editable datatable

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I am trying to add validations for the primeng editable datatable in angular 2 project. Can anyone let me know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template tag, and then set the formControlName inside of it.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="tickets" [editable]="true">
  <p-column field="id" header="Number" [editable]="true">
    <ng-template let-col let-ticket="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
      <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="id" [(ngModel)]="ticket[col.field]"/>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="name" header="Name" [editable]="true">
     <ng-template let-col let-ticket="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
      <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="ticket[col.field]"/>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```